# Passing a function or lambda to create a new dataframe column (series)

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to pass a function to create a new column, such as:

```
def myfunction(row):
    print (row) # see what is being passed for now...
    return ...

df['new_col'] = my_function(df)
```

Normally I've done all creation "in-place", such as:

```
df['new_col'] = df['first_name'] + ' ' + df['last_name']
```

But let's suppose I want to do something much fancier and pass it to a function or lambda. How could I do that?

Comment: Your approach would be much better, why do you want to do it some other way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something

```
def myfunction(x, y):
         return ' '.join([x,y])
     
df['new'] = df.apply(lambda x : myfunction(x['a'],x['b']), axis=1)
```

Comment: just to clarify: `axis=1` means each item is traversed as a row?

Comment: @David542 yes, that is per row check ~

Comment: got it, so I could also just do: `df.apply(myfunction, axis=1)` and do all the formatting in the function right?

Comment: @David542 yes, but this will need you change the function a little bit

Comment: cool, so it could be `return ' '.join([row['a'], row['b'])` ?

Comment: @David542 yes that is correct . `def myfunction(row):
    ...:     return ' '.join([row['a'], row['b']])
    ...: 
    ...: 
    ...: df['new'] = df.apply(myfunction,axis=1)`

Comment: This is a *worse* solution